# Create a new record in form LedgerJournalTransCustPaym through x++ code

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I need to create a reord in `LedgerJournalTrans` through x++ code.

While debugging I found out that the class `LedgerJournalEngine_CustPayment` is used to initiate the form as

```
LedgerJournalEngine_CustPayment  = new LedgerJournalEngine_CustPayment(element)
```

and later

```
LedgerJournalEngine.initValue(LedgerJournalTrans);
```

also after assiging the `accountNum` the methods executed at the `modified()` method of datasource field `LedgerJournalTrans:AccountNum` are `element.accountNumModifiedPost();` etc.

While trying to achieve the same through code I am not able to initiate the class `LedgerJournalEngine_CustPayment` and also the other methods in the form `LedgerJournalTransCustPaym` that system does.

Pls Help..
Joyce

Comment: Why are you not able to initiate the class?

Comment: As it is expecting `new LedgerJournalEngine_CustPayment(element)
` and when I just do `new LedgerJournalEngine_CustPayment()` from X++ code i get error

Comment: Try call it with null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LedgerJournalEngine* classes are mostly used by the forms to do work and execute code before/after events and datasource actions.  What you're trying to do, it would probably just make more sense to complete all of the necessary ledgerJournalTrans fields, then do a .insert().  Here is some code I wrote that will do what you want though using the engine some:

```
static void Job81(Args _args)
{
    LedgerJournalEngine_CustPayment ledgerJournalEngine;
    LedgerJournalTable              ledgerJournalTable;
    LedgerJournalTrans              ledgerJournalTrans;
    NumberSeq                       numberSeq;
    Voucher                         voucher;
    ;

    // This just selects the header you are inserting into
    select firstonly ledgerJournalTable where ledgerJournalTable.JournalNum == 'GB 0056226';

    if (!ledgerJournalTable)
        throw error ("Unable to find journal table record");


    ledgerJournalTrans.initValue();

    numberSeq = NumberSeq::newGetNumFromCode(ledgerJournalTable.VoucherSeries);

    if (numberSeq)
    {
        ledgerJournalTrans.Voucher      = numberSeq.num();
        voucher                         = ledgerJournalTrans.Voucher;
    }

    ledgerJournalTrans.JournalNum       = ledgerJournalTable.JournalNum;
    ledgerJournalTrans.TransDate        = SystemDateGet();
    ledgerJournalTrans.AccountType      = LedgerjournalACType::Cust;
    ledgerJournalTrans.AccountNum       = '100003';

    ledgerJournalEngine = LedgerJournalEngine::construct(LedgerJournalType::CustPayment);
    ledgerJournalEngine.newJournalActive(ledgerJournalTable);
    ledgerJournalEngine.accountModified(ledgerJournalTrans);
    ledgerJournalTrans.AmountCurCredit  = 10;
    ledgerJournalTrans.OffsetAccountType    = ledgerJournalTable.OffsetAccountType;
    ledgerJournalTrans.OffsetAccount        = ledgerJournalTable.OffsetAccount;
    ledgerJournalTrans.CurrencyCode         = CompanyInfo::standardCurrency();
    ledgerJournalEngine.currencyModified(ledgerJournalTrans);
    ledgerJournalTrans.insert();

    if (numberSeq   && ledgerJournalTrans.Voucher   == voucher)
    {
        numberSeq.used();
    }
    else
    {
        if (numberSeq)
            numberSeq.abort();
    }

    info("Done");
}
```

Comment: just what i was lookin for... thanks for the effort, appreciate it.